# How would you handle a colleague offering your PhD student a postdoc position?

Tags: phd, advisor, ethics, postdocs, conflict-of-interest

How would you handle a colleague offering your PhD student a postdoc position?
I had applied and received fund for him to continue with me as a postdoc immediately he graduates. We had this discussion before the application. Now I'm informed that a colleague offered him a longer postdoc contract (+2 year) and he's accepted to work with him. I spent years training this student in this field and we work very well. So I believe the extra two years is what was used to attract him.

I need opinions to make sure I don't appear confrontational or bring my ability to finalize this student's PhD supervision without bias to question.

**Some points:**

- Politically, I think I am disadvantaged to have direct confrontation with this colleague. My position is under contract. And my work visa is dependent on keeping my job.
- The student in question is on a student visa and I believe he wanted to stay longer hence going for his offer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141014/discussion-on-question-by-boltzbooz-how-would-you-handle-a-colleague-offering-yo).

Comment: _I had applied and received fund for him to continue with me as a postdoc immediately he graduates._ - Is this normal in some fields?  In pure math, it is very unusual to do a postdoc with your PhD advisor.

Comment: "You have learned well, grasshopper."

Comment: @Kimball In my experience in psychology, it's not common, but certainly not that unusual if people have projects/experiments ongoing.

Comment: Sorry to say it, but you sound a bit like a parent who is disappointed when their child reaches adulthood and makes their own decisions about their future. You should be congratulating yourself on a job well done.

Comment: Would you clarify if the PhD student applied to the other position, or was your colleague reaching out pro-actively? In the former case, would your colleague be bound to treat the application confidentially in your country/at your institution?

Comment: The position was not advertised. Not to the public at least. He was approached as he's close to one of my colleague's postdoc. I understand I have no control over this but I feel this is unfair to me. I shouldn't have a problem with this but the manner of approach from both of them is wrong. Especially from my colleague. We have sat together and had lunch on various occasions and he didn't think to bring it up. If the position was advertised publicly, then I understand my student can apply to whatever position he likes.

Comment: Why do you think confronting your colleague would put your visa in danger? I guess your colleague and you are working on similar topics (since he tries to draft your student), so peaceful discussions would be beneficial for all three of you in the future.

Comment: Long comment: If your student had agreed to continue with you, then at least you deserved him notifying you about their decision. Perhaps that's how you learned about the whole situation, in which case the student is behaving professionally. OTOH, I do believe your colleague should've discussed their plans with you before making the offer. However, they weren't obligated to do so. This is a lesson on how this particular colleague handles things professionally that you should take into account in future interactions.

Comment: Once your student finishes their PhD they are officially an independent mathematician in the job market, and you are one of their potential employers. They were offered a job they prefer and that seem to suit their career and life goals. If you do not have a better offer, or if they were originally interested in your offer but found a better one, congratulate them and let them continue with their career. There is no need for any further action, specially if no contract was signed with you originally (but there is not enough detail to say more here).

Comment: In this, Academia is no different than the professional world, at least in my part of the US. You can have a prospective employee all the way through on-boarding and shazzam, they end up taking a job elsewhere for more (money, benefits, whatever). Wish them well and ensure you remember their name.

Answer (score 89):

You don't own your students; your role is to educate them and teach them about their field - in terms of content, in terms of conduct of research, and in terms of navigating the professional environment.

One of the first marks of your success in this process is the successful graduation of your student.

A further mark of success will be if your student is able to find a next position that suits them and furthers their career goals.

It seems that most academics agree that for a student who wants an academic career (which usually means eventual hiring as a professor, though there may be other long-term options in some fields) it's important that they demonstrate some independence in their post doctoral years, meaning that they do work separate from their PhD advisor. Ideally, this would be at a different institution, but another advisor at the same institution is better than the same advisor.

You can congratulate your student on their new position, wish them well, offer them support and a place to turn to advice in their future, etc.

For their remaining time as your student, there's no good reason for you to have nor to demonstrate any ill-will towards them for taking a job that's best for them. If you're feeling upset or like you can't advise them in their best interests because of some perceived snub, that sounds to me like a personal problem for you to resolve that shouldn't involve either your colleague or the student directly.

---

A commenter pointed out that you may be specifically bothered because you've obtained funding for this student to continue with you as a post doc. Given that information, I think the courtesy owed depends a lot on additional information not provided here, but it wouldn't change my overall answer too much. You say that *you* applied for funds, and that you had a discussion before the application.

It's not really fair to expect a student to be ready to commit at that point - yes, if they don't have any other options at that point, they certainly are going to want you to produce an opportunity for them. On the other hand, they can't stop all other plans just because your application for funding *might* be successful.

It is possible that you both reached a mutual agreement that the student would continue in your lab as a post doc, and that now they've accepted a *different* position without letting you know. I still think it's important to recognize that the student has to keep their own best interests in mind, and that staying in the same lab that they did their PhD work is probably not in their best interest, especially if they have another offer for a longer duration.

However, it's also possible that you've done these things more unilaterally, and I don't think it's fair to consider obtaining funds for a student or offering them a job because *you* want them to work with you to be any constraint on them should they choose to go elsewhere, nor should colleagues see it as a limit on whether they can make their own offers to the student; there's no "calling dibs". Hopefully you can use the funds to hire a different post doc, and if not, then you should have had a more concrete agreement ahead of time.

Comment: 100% agreed in principle, but I think your answer doesn't consider "I had applied and received fund (sic!) for him...We had this discussion before the application." While it's best to let bygones be bygones, and what you write describes the general situation of transitioning Ph.D. -> PostDoc well, a conversation with the other PI strikes me as in order. And the student should have at least mentioned it given that they were on board with OP securing funding.

Comment: @gnometorule Thanks; I had interpreted that more along the lines of "I have funds that could fund a post doc and offered a position"; though OP may have had this student in mind for that position, they didn't say that the student accepted the position, only that they discussed it, and at least in my experience with grants unless it's something like a fellowship that is really to the *trainee*, a grant for a post doc is for *a* post doc, not a *specific* person.

Comment: @BryanKrause don't you think the colleague should have informed the OP that they are reaching out to the student as a courtesy? While I completely agree with the main gist of your answer and see no issue with the student's actions, it does feel like the colleague acted in an underhanded way.

Comment: With respect to "handling" his colleague, do you think it's appropriate to say something like "Hey, I'm glad ___ found a good spot in your lab. In the future, would you give me a heads-up on plans like that, just to help me plan a little better?"

Comment: @terdon Maybe, but only if the colleague was in contact with OP and knew he was pursuing funding specifically for this student, which I doubt is the case.

Comment: This answer is mainly unsolicited advice. Where does OP ask about the PhD student's behavior?

Comment: @terdon If the question were asked from the opposite perspective, maybe I'd recommend it as a courtesy. It's not clear who reached out to who, though - just as likely the student asked the other professor about a position. I don't think the other professor has any duty to share the information before the student has accepted their offer, either - that implies that the PhD advisor has some control over the student's post doc job search that they shouldn't have. I'd think differently if the student was changing grad advisors or leaving a postdoc early.

Comment: @fectin I think that could be reasonable to ask, but I'd be careful not to imply that there is an expectation that offers need to be approved in advance. I'd also consider that a colleague may be wary of causing retaliation against the student. It's an unfortunately common complaint that some PIs try to hold on to their students past their earning graduation; a PI that feels like someone is trying to 'steal' their student might respond by delaying their graduation so that they get the work out of them they feel they deserve.

Comment: @fectin thank you. This is exactly the reason I feel bad about this. The position wasn't advertised. He was approached apparently. I can't hold my student back from doing what he thinks is best for him but this poaching may get worse in the future. We can even see postdocs switching to different labs under first year of contract.

Comment: @BoltzBooz "We can even see postdocs switching to different labs under first year of contract." Then you should work on being more attractive. If other labs appear more desirable, that's an issue for your lab to solve, not something that requires changes by the other labs.

Comment: @Roland You somehow believe that the problem is from the losing group which in this case is mine. But it's not. We have seen PhD students leave to work in the industry after a year or two. We have also noticed same tends in some postdocs. Some of them complete the first year before leaving. We can't do anything about this as some of them are in the country to stay. So they go for any option that guarantees longer stay and more pay. This also applies to switching groups. What this means is that Prof A does the ground work of bringing a postdoc into the country and the university. Then Prof B wi

Comment: @BoltzBooz Your question here isn't about you bringing in a postdoc and then someone else in your department hiring them away before they completed their time, it's about a graduate student who has completed their time with you. In any event, I don't find your comment very convincing re: Roland's suggestion - it sounds like you're not providing the best opportunities, so people go elsewhere. They have that right; you don't own a person just because you hired them first.

Answer (score 33):

Why do you want to "handle" your colleague? It is nice for the student to receive multiple offers and choose what's best for them. It is also nice for the student to be exposed to different research groups, mentors and supervisors before they become an established researcher and form their own group.

You may be able to keep the funds and use them to invite another postdoc, which means you would not lose the funding. It all seems rather a win-win situation and I am not sure why you consider confronting your colleague on it.

Comment: Concerning 'Why do you want to "handle" your colleague?': I think it is a rather natural reaction to be disappointed, and from that emotional state all sorts of irrational thoughts may follow. Nothing wrong with that. It is just advisable not to act out of the emotion.

Comment: Sure, but Dmitry is asking "why" in the sense of "what professionally defensible well-thought-out reason do you have...", not "what fart of brain-chemistry is causing this emotion".

Comment: @Ben, I do not think that kind of language gets us anywhere.

Answer (score 13):

Your colleague did nothing wrong here (most likely).

The only questionable behavior comes from your student - IF you have clearly communicated the intended postdoc and IF the student clearly affirmed they are on board with it. If that is the case, you have every right to sit down with them and discuss why are they breaking the promises they gave so explicitly, and it triggers some kind of a crisis resolution sequence which all three of you will have to navigate.

However, if that is not as unambiguous, I would consider actively clawing them back abusive, as you are clearly currently in a position of power with respect to the student, and they may feel threatened by the confrontation. Students are a bit like children - like others have said, you have to do what is best for them, not make them instruments of your personal ambition. And being able to independently (!) find a new job with better prospects than you could offer (!) is a great career step.

On the flip side, you could be on the other end of this arrangement and become the one poaching others' students. To avoid situations like yours, I would advise asking students about the possible conflict of interest they may already be in and helping them to solve this issue ethically by raising their awareness of the other perspectives.

Comment: An interesting answer (+1), but even here, a "promise" to take on a particular professional role is always subject to other better offers coming along --- that is a natural expectation in almost every profession when dealing with job applicants (save perhaps the military or the mafia).  It is always an inconvenience when good employees leave to go to greener pastures, but that is part of management.  This is why employment contracts typically are not signed in blood.

Comment: @Ben Maybe I am reading too much into the original post, but I got an impression of OP learning about the student leaving for greener pastures from third parties. And this is problematic, because then the situation becomes "I am pouring resources into you being under assumption you will continue working in my lab for a while and it will bear fruit in 2-3 years time. I am also willing to accept the risk you jump the ship at the last moment, but you already know you would be working elsewhere and keep me in the dark; I would still then need to invest resources, but differently".

Answer (score 4):

You have to think long-term.  You may feel disappointed now but your working relationship with students does not end when they graduate or they move on to a new position.  For example, I have had a student who graduated more than ten years ago started working with me again.    Just wish them success, be helpful whenever you can, and continue to maintain a good working relationship with them.   You will never know what happens in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would think about it on the bright side. You have trained your student so successfully that another professor is happy to offer them a long-term postdoc position. This is nothing bad for all three parties: You get a testimonial for your education, your student gets a bright future, and your colleague gets a helping hand at their lab. I see no reason to confront anyone.

If you're worried about your postdoc funding, you can seek another candidate to support your projects. A postdoc candidate is nothing unreplaceable. It's completely reasonable to expect your "replacement" workforce to catch up with your project in a month or two.

Comment: *It's completely reasonable to expect your "replacement" workforce to catch up with your project in a month or two*  I think thst this depends a lot on the nature of the field,

Answer (score -3):

You can't prevent the PhD doing his fellowship elsewhere, in spite of his apparent ["breach of promise"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breach_of_promise).

You will appreciate that having a good communicative connection between student and adviser is in most cases a large part of any success they may enjoy together. But you say your relations with the student are good so this suggests that he is not leaving you because he finds your colleague more congenial; rather more because he was offered a 2 year program and took this as he wants to stay in the country.

Naturally you feel aggrieved that your efforts in training this person on techniques vital to the field you work in have effectively been stolen by your colleague. And thinking that this situation could be repeated again must be dispiriting for you.

I think that a lot depends on your present Head of Department and his sensibility to his staff's situations. If (and only if) you adjudge your HoD to be appreciative to your situation, you might try talking to him on the matter. Terdon commented that where a PhD student agreed prior to application to be your nominee for a fellowship bid, then your colleague's "poaching" of him showed scant courtesy to your time investment in him let alone good collegial relations. Your HoD of course may agree or not.

But whatever happens, you have learned that when you intend making a big time commitment in training a PhD with a view to retaining him for later work, you have to evaluate *character* at least as much as intelligence or energy. A student who is voicing anxieties about his visa security or his girlfriend in another part of the country may really be creating for himself a plausible exit route from future commitment to your research group. We all have to learn to "read the signs" in others' behavior in order to avoid disappointment.

Comment: *when you intend making a big time commitment in training a PhD with a view to retaining him for later work* the premise here is completely flawed. No one should be training a PhD with a view to 'retaining him'. Thinking about students in this way is appalling.

Comment: No one should. But in practice many academics do harbor this expectation after putting in a lot of one-to-one training and discussion. Academics are ambitious (in fairness they have to be in the context of modern Academia and its funding) and cannot relish the time lost teaching the same old techniques and perspectives to every new guy into their group. For sure OP's poaching colleague didn't relish mentoring a greenhorn Fellow . . . Perhaps you can suggest a fair procedure here ?

Comment: Referring to this as 'poaching' is also completely unacceptable. You do not own your students. The 'exchange' for training a PhD student is they perform research with you while under your supervision. There should be no expectation beyond that. The 'fair procedure' here is that OP congratulates their student and moves on with their life.

Comment: Not poaching ? But not good form either, is it ? And your proffered fair procedure would not reproach this. Which would encourage this in other senior faculty - in turn demoralizing the hard-working junior staff. Individual academic freedom brings some obligation to consider the department's other faculty and their aspirations.

Comment: Speaking from physical sciences experience, what many PIs do is to have one or two postdocs in their group who have done their doctorates under the PI. These fellows then train the entrant PhDs in the techniques and other routine matters. This duty transfer frees up some time for the PI. Sadly, some PIs take this too far and have the fellows well-nigh supervise the PhDs, something that is *not* part of their duties and something that is extremely unfair on both fellows and PhD students. But technique training by fellows is okay. Maybe OP had this role in mind for his fellow ?

Comment: @Trunk Whatever ideas OP has for roles of their students does not bind the students to filling those roles. If it did, that would imply the PhD advisor has some ownership of the student post-graduation. They do not.

Comment: Well, PhD students are offered programs entailing 10-20 hours demo/TA work. I wouldn't be surprised if fellows' contracts had unspecified departmental duties. Even if not, it might be something that the past PhD fellow might feel *morally* obliged to do. It is not a very balanced relationship between fellow and tenured PI.

Comment: Training by fellows is OK, but those fellows should come from elsewhere and the PhD graduates should go gathering experience to other, in Europe preferably abroad, places. The supervisor should seek postdocs from other universities. The graduates need experience from somewhere else for their career. In our place we are required to get foreign experience even if we want to return and do tenure track back home.

Comment: @Vladimir F Героям слава  Absolutely ! 'New blood' policy should prevail. And no returning 'home' to the university they graduated from so they can get easy tenure and a 30 year long research and teaching mediocrity.